# Missing "|" vertical line in multirow & multicolumn table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am missing a vertical line in this multirow & multicolumn table.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
    \caption{Example}
\begin{tabular}{l||ccccc|c|c}%hier zwischen dann die breite in {\textwidth}
    \hline
     & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Text} & \multirow{2}{*}{Text} & \multirow{2}{*}{Text} \\
     & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & & \\
    \hline
    Text & 1 & 0 & 3 & - & 2 & 5 & 5 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: pdf]

Comment: here `\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Text}`